# Internet explorer Javascript issue with loop

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer

I have a large app that I use
for (var i in array) and it worked well, till I see that in IE in Windows 8
It doesn't work because it returns as one of its indexes the property: indexOf
I understand now that it was not a good practice to do it, but is there a way that I can still use it in IE (as it works for other browsers).
Do they have some kind of backward compatible?

Comment: use a normal `for` loop?

Comment: or the `forEach` array method, e.g. `myArray.forEach(function(value, index) { ... });`

Comment: See the answers to the linked question. You *can* use `for-in` with arrays, but it's not what it's for, and if you add an enumerable property to `Array.prototype` (as you apparently are to shim `indexOf`), you have to include `hasOwnProperty` calls (demonstrated in a couple of the answers there).

Comment: As a side note: On most vaguely-current versions of IE, you could make `indexOf` **non-enumerable**. But I think all of the ones where you can do that also have `indexOf` natively, so...